# "Package Installer has stopped" - My app works fine on the Emulator and USB Debugging but built apk can't be installed on real phone

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am developing an app with android studio and it installs and runs well via the emulator and also when connect to a phone via USB debugging. However, when I generate a signed apk and attempt to install it on the same device it was working via usb debugging, "the package installer stops".

Android Studio Version 3.0
Android Version on Device 7.0

I first uninstalled any existing version of the app on the phone before attempting to install.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What is the device, what version of Android, what version of AS?  Did you check the error logs to find more info? can you post those?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar problem with Android 6.0.1 (API level 22). All was working fine in Android 5.1.1 and under. So when I installed it in 6 I got "the package installer stops" every time I try to access google maps. After so many search i found out that was permissions.

```
private void checkPermissionToUseLocation() {
        boolean isLocationPermitted = PermissionUtil.hasAllPermissions((Activity) context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
//I put the below code and every thing goes fine
        if (!isLocationPermitted) {
            PermissionUtil.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }
```

Its make the app ask for permissions at execly time that i try to access the map not only in the install.